# How to get help on a julia macro?

Tags: macros, julia

I am wondering how to get help on a Julia macro or at least find the sourcefile where it is defined. For example, I know there is a macro @spawnat. 
But if I try doing

```
> julia> help( @spawnat )  
ErrorException("wrong number of arguments")
```

or

```
> help( spawnat ) 
ErrorException("spawnat not defined")
```

Which is not great...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Put it in quotation marks:

```
julia> help("@spawnat")
```

gives

```
Base.@spawnat()

Accepts two arguments, "p" and an expression, and runs the
expression asynchronously on processor "p", returning a
"RemoteRef" to the result.
```

You can get help on the help function with `help(help)`.

Comment: Ironically, `help("?")` and `??` don't seem to work. How does one get more information about `?`

Comment: Hah. That's amusing. `help(help)` and `?help` will work, but we should make `??` and `help("?")` work too. Issue opened: https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/issues/6243.